# SELECT CAST(number1 AS REAL) / number3;

Tags: sql

I'm confused about

```
SELECT CAST(number1 AS REAL) / number3;
```

which I've got no exmaple to refer to. Anyone can explain this to me?

Comment: CAST converts a value to specified data type (e.g. real).

Answer (score 0):

You can read here about cast/convert (which can be found also with a short search in google "cast ms sql"): 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx